# what is the most effective way to keep records of number of uniqie article views

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to create an article based website using codeigniter. When any article is requested to fetch from database for viewing, I use the following code to mark the number of unique view of each article in a separate table called "hits".

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO hits(ip,article_slug,hitcount) 
             VALUES('$ip_address','$id',1)
           ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE hitcount=hitcount+0");
```

I take the IP address of the user and get the value of article_slug from $this->uri->segment(3);
and then run the above mysql query.

I am using the IP address here to get the number of unique views, but it suddenly occurs to me that several people could be using the same IP address. So in that case my query above doesn't seem effective.

So I was wondering what is the most effective way to do it. One of my friends was talking about doing it using cookies instead of IP address. Do you think its a good idea or there is a better way of doing it?

Could you please give me an idea on how to do this?

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: cookies wouldn't give you a definitive count as they can always be cleared and then you'd re count the same machine.

Comment: I don't think it is possible on the level you want. I have a dynamic ip. If i view the site, it'l increase the number of hits but i am the same person. Or there can be shared ip. Means your hit count will be less than what it should be.

Comment: I don't think there's a simple way to do this. You can't rely on IP addresses or cookies to reliably identify an individual. You might get slightly more accurate results if you make users sign up and then log in before they can see read each page, and then track those hits, but there's a goodly amount of work involved in setting that up; forcing people to sign in to read articles will turn people off from your site; and there's no way to guarantee that someone only has one account anyway. That said, if you're prepared to accept some uncertainty, I'd recommend the cookie approach.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Google Analytics and setting up a Custom Report that tracks only article views. This would give you the insights you seek plus a lot more and it would avoid counting bots (like Google, Bing or a SPAMer).

But if you defiantly want to track users on your own I would recommend tracking the IP address in one field and Session ID in another.

```
session_start();

$user['ip']  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$user['sid'] = session_id();
```

Comment: The good point of this is : reduce load on MySQL by a lot and apache also.

Comment: @user1390126 Thanks a lot for your reply. But if I use google analytics would I be able to show the number of article views beside the article in my website?

Comment: If you use a SESSION, though, won't it be re-set when the user closes their browser down?

Comment: Yes, you can do that in real time using Google Analytics API, but I would recommend only grabbing the data once an hour (or so) and store that in your articles MySQL table. Add another row 'page_views' and when you load the article you will load the most recent known number of page views.

Comment: I just updated my account (I was user1390126). andrewsi: yes, you could detect the SID from the users cookies, if it doesn't exist you could start the session, set a cookie "SID" to the same as the users SID. If however the cookie SID is set you can set the session ID session_id($cookie['sid']) prior to session_start();

Comment: @MikeG . Is this what you are suggesting?  http://www.google.com/analytics/features/content.html

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind using cookie is that if some group of user is behind proxy you will get same ip-address for all the user who read your article which is wrong.

So you can use combo of both and that way you could get better results. You can either use cookie or session. But if you use cookie and give it an expiry period of about a year or more and if you specify some unique hash to the cookie (which could be md5 of the log table's primary key) and then you can track users pretty well.

let me know if you do not understand what I mean.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried to grasp the idea of what you tried to meant but I have failed. Could you please explain a bit more with some examples of code.(that way it would be easier for me) Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I also have question .. why should I set an expiry period of about a year or more? Please explain this also. Thanks

Comment: Sure, When you set expiry time on cookie that cookie will exist in your visitors browser as long as user clears all cookies manually or cookie expires itself after specified period of time which could be either year or 20 year as you wish. But year or 2 could be practical as people either change their browser or laptop/computer within 2/4 years. :-)

Comment: You can even consider using Google Analytics or piwik (http://piwik.org) for better reporting and analytics.